# Perl using a variable to reference a module messes up passing parameters

Tags: perl, perl-module

I have a problem when using a variable to reference a module, it seems to mess up the passing of the variables:

#### TOTO.pm

```
package TOTO;

use Data::Dumper;

sub print {
       print Dumper(@_);
}
```

#### Perl program

```
package main;

TOTO::print('Hello World');
print ">>>>>>>>>>>\n";
my $package = 'TOTO';

$package->print('Hello World');
```

And the output is:

```
$VAR1 = 'Hello World';
>>>>>>>>>>>
$VAR1 = 'TOTO';
$VAR2 = 'Hello World';
```

Any advice on how to avoid having `TOTO` passed as the first variable?

Comment: I posted a comment which clearly came across as "curt."  I didn't mean to make it unpleasant, just meant to ask for clarification of something I didn't understand. I apologize. Here is the question I had. What do you want to accomplish with a package name in a variable and then with using the arrow operator on it? This is usually done with objects. Knowing the purpose helps me in putting together a more suitable answer.

Comment: `\&{ $package . '::print' }->()`

Comment: No offense taken, I am German. We are curt by default. 
I have module which evaluates at the beginning if it is possible to load an XS module, else another one (fallback):
`
package Adaptor;

our $reference;
eval{require(xs::module)}
if($@){$reference = "nonxs::module"}
else{$reference = "xs::module"}
$reference->method_call();
`
Several method names in the xs module are the same as in the Adaptor.pm, so when I export, they are overwritten. Hence the idea was to store the reference to the object in a variable. I will now rename the methods in the xs module and export. Thanks you!

Comment: @juettemann  That's a relief! Thank you for the response. I'd always recommend cleaning up conflicts first. if possible. Thanks for explaining it, I see now what you meant with it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Short:**  The observed behavior comes from use of `->` on a package name.

The arrow operator is used with a reference or with an object, which itself is a reference to a data structure that has been `bless`-ed into its class. (Or with a class name, see below.) That object or the class name is quietly passed as the first argument so that the whole system would work. Note that the package in the question does *not* define a class (objects cannot be created with it).

From [Arrow operator in perlop](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#The-Arrow-Operator)

> "-> " is an infix dereference operator, just as it is in C and C++. If the right side is either a [...] , {...} , or a (...) subscript, then the left side must be either a hard or symbolic reference to an array, a hash, or a subroutine respectively. (Or technically speaking, a location capable of holding a hard reference, if it's an array or hash reference being used for assignment.)  See [perlreftut](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlreftut.html) and [perlref](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlref.html).

It continues, to statements of direct interest in this problem

> Otherwise, the right side is a method name or a simple scalar variable containing either the method name or a subroutine reference, and the left side must be either an object (a blessed reference) or a class name (that is, a package name).  See [perlobj](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlobj.html).

So in uses related to classes the left-hand side may contain the class name, and class methods can then be invoked on it (or it can be just queried). Given that a class is a package then this *is* a package name.

The situation in the question falls within this so the package name is passed to the subroutine. However, according to the above quote it seems that the sub can only be a *method*, which isn't the case here. So it may be that this use of `->` should really be disallowed.  Either way, using it on a package which isn't a class strikes me as mistaken.

---

*Update to clarification*.  This use was intended, to resolve an ambiguity in which package was loaded. The package name is saved into a variable and then the sub invoked on it, using the arrow operator. In this case code would have to be added to the sub to handle the first argument (package name) which is passed regardless of the invocation, by the courtesy of the arrow operator.  But then we would have to allow a case when this *is* invoked on an object, ending up with a code that covers two distinct uses. I believe that it is better to change to a design that does not involve all this.

---

If you want to use a package, say as a library

**File TOTO.pm**

```
pacakge TOTO;

use Exporter;
our (@ISA, @EXPORT_OK);
@ISA = ('Exporter');
@EXPORT_OK = qw(prn);   # This can be asked for by user of package

use Data::Dumper;

sub prn {
       print Dumper(@_);
}

1;  # important for 'require' when this is used
```

I've changed the sub name to `prn` so that it's not a Perl library function.  The main script

```
use warnings;
use strict;

use TOTO qw(prn);

prn("Hello World");
```

The fully qualified name `TOTO::prn()` can always be used.  If you wanted to make this a class that would require a bit more in the package.

This package, `TOTO`, does not export anything by default, unless asked for.  That's what `@EXPORT_OK` sets up and that's why we need to list functions to import into `main::` when `use TOTO`.  Start, for example, with [perlmod](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlmod.html)

Comment: Using a variable as a class name is very useful in testing. Say you want to create 50 new objects in a test file, each inside of it's own scope. Instead of typing `my $obj = Some::Module::Somewhere->new;` 50 times, I usually do: `my $mod = 'Some::Module::Somewhere';` (global scope) then, each time I need an object, `my $obj = $mod->new;`. Much shorter :)

Comment: @stevieb  OK, thanks for that -- I use the class name occasionally as well. But this is not a class -- OP sets up a package.

Comment: a package is a class: [A class is simply a package: perlobj](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlobj.html#A-Class-is-Simply-a-Package)

Comment: @stevieb  No, a package is not a class. If you don't bless in it you can't create objects.  You turned the quote around: _A class is a package_, the other way round is not true.

Comment: @stevieb  That's a nice trick you have there :)  Is everything OK with import hiearchies etc?

Comment: Unless there are edge cases I haven't triggered, I've never had an issue :)

Answer (score 2):

In the simplest terms, to create an object-oriented `TOTO` module you must create a file `TOTO.pm` that contains at least a constructor subroutine `new`

```
package TOTO;

sub new {
    bless {};
}

sub print {
    print "I am a TOTO object\n";
}

1;
```

That code must be saved in a file called `TOTO.pm`that must match the `package TOTO` name in the source

Then you may write a program, say `main.pl`, that uses that module. For instance

```
use strict;
use warnings 'all';

use TOTO;

my $object = TOTO->new;

$object->print;
```

And then you have created a new `TOTO` object that says what it is

If I run

```
$ perl main.pl
```

I get the output

```
I am a TOTO object
```

You will want to make this code more useful, and there are many variations on this theme, but those are the basics

Answer (score 1):

That's just how Perl's package system works. You need to handle this yourself in the sub being called. You can't change it prior to the call.

```
sub print {
    # special variable __PACKAGE__ contains "TOTO"

    if ($_[0] eq __PACKAGE__ || ref $_[0] eq __PACKAGE__){
        shift; # throw away class/object
    } 
    print Dumper(@_);
}
```

The `ref $_[0]` part isn't technically needed, because you don't have a constructor in your class (you call the method on the class only, but it will just do the right thing if you ever do use objects without having to change anything later).

Comment: When *blessed*, `$_[0]` could not be *`equal`* to *package name*!

Comment: Nope, that's why I use `|| ref $_[0] ...`, which catches the case where it is a blessed reference. Much like `ref $thing eq 'HASH'`

Comment: Thanks @stevieb, this might come in handy in the future.

Answer (score 1):

Here's the issue

> Any advice on how to avoid having TOTO passed as the first variable?

You've discovered the answer yourself. This works fine

```
TOTO::print('Hello World');
```

If you call it as

```
TOTO->print('Hello World');
```

then you're asking for perl to call `print` as a class method and pass `('TOTO', 'Hello World')` as parameters to the `TOTO::print` subroutine

If `TOTO` is just a bunch of subroutines then, as you found, just call `TOTO::totosub`

Answer (score 0):

Check differences between this:

```
TOTO::print("Hello World");
```

and

```
TOTO->print("Hello World");
```

which is not proper object notation, because `TOTO` is just a string.

Syntaxe `object->function(arguments)` whil pass `object` as 1st argument, to be stored as `$this`, for sample.

```
sub print {
    my $this = shift @_;
    print Dumper(@_);
}
```

May do the job (even if not blessed object).

Try this:

```
package TOTO;
use Data::Dumper;
sub new { return bless {}, shift; }

sub print {
    my $self = shift @_;
    if   ( scalar $self =~ /=HASH\(/ ) {
        print Dumper(@_);
    } else {
        print Dumper($self);
    }
}

package main;

my $package = TOTO->new();

$package->print("Hello World");

TOTO::print("Hello World");
```

This could output:

```
$VAR1 = 'Hello World';
$VAR1 = 'Hello World';
```

And have a look at `man perlobj`, `man perlootut` and `man perlmodlib`

Comment: That'll work, but it'll break `TOTO::print()`. The string passed in will be put into `$this`.

Comment: also, technically, `TOTO->print()` is valid. It's no different than `my $log = Log::Log4perl->get_logger;` Note also that it's a bareword, not a quoted string.

Comment: @stevieb Especially, in `man perlobj`, search for ***bareword***!  *<<...it sometimes interprets a bareword's meaning incorrectly. For example, the construct `Class->new()` can be interpreted as either `'Class'->new()` or  `Class()->new()`...>>*

Comment: Are you familiar with Perl? `TOTO->print("Hello World")` is a perfectly good object-oriented call. It is a call to the *class method* `print`, and you usually see it as a call to the constructor `my $object = TOTO->new`.

Comment: @Borodin In `TOTO->print()`, `TOTO` is a *bareword*, It could be interpreter as `TOTO()->print` or `'TOTO'->print`... I don't like barewords! (Even for opening a file I prefer `open my $handler` than `open HANDLER`... But it's my own feeling). This could spare a lot of border effect wich could make hard debug of strange behaviours... In fact: You're right `TOTO->print()` is a perfectly good object-oriented call... in a perfect world... but could leed to strange behaviours in badly written scripts..

Comment: @F.Hauri: I think you are out of touch with modern Perl. If you insist, then you may call `my $toto = 'TOTO'->new`, but Perl has a [DWIM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DWIM) approach so that both work fine. If there is any substance behind ***" I don't like barewords! "*** then please post a new question, otherwise I think you are distracting from the original question.